# How to Convert .NET DateTime to JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

My WCF webservice is returning C# DateTime objects as JSON like this,

"/Date(1293793200000+1300)/"

I have found this,

[Converting .NET DateTime to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016847/converting-net-datetime-to-json)

Which suggests this method for converting it using javascript,

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(1245398693390);
document.write(d);
```

The difference is that my date format has the +1300 in it, which seems to be my timezone, as I am +13 hours from GMT.

Can I somehow modify my service to adjust the value to an absolute number of milliseconds from epoch or can the javascript be modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore the time zone offset - the number of milliseconds is always relative to UTC (see the "DateTime wire format" section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx). The offset mostly indicates that the original `DateTime` value was of `DateTimeKind.Local`, but the serialized milliseconds since the epoch is always relative to GMT.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the DateTime object in .NET to a string and just serialize the string. That's what I did. See [Proper way to format date from database using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649057/proper-way-to-format-date-from-database-using-javascript-jquery)